# S3 Access column shows "Error" for all buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my console, all buckets show "Error" at the access column. Every operation results in an error, being it uploading, downloading, deleting or modifying files. The only thing I can do is creating a bucket. Afterwards however, I can't do anything with it.

I always had access rights and was previously working with my current account. I even tried it with the root account without any success. This seems to have happened miraculously over night as I wasn't working with S3 much during the past days.

N.B. I don't use any other APIs beside the console.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of googling and trying things out, I finally found out what the origin of the problem was: The browser.

If you encounter this problem try logging in via incognito mode. If the issue is now magically solved, then chances are, some plugin caused the problem, mainly those blocking ads. In my case it was "Avira Browserschutz" but I read that "uBlock Origin" may cause the same issue.

Comment: It is weird though. I had the plugin since ages and never encountered this issue before...

Answer (score 8):

In your IAM policy permission, you have to add following permission for S3 console to list all your buckets properly (without error).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Console_List_S3_Buckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
}
```

Comment: I think, this should be the accepted answer. If you observe the "Access" column on S3 tabular display is all about showing the access level permissions for the bucket and its objects. This information is not retrieved from a single source, while from multiple APIs specially the "GetBucketAcl, GetBucketPolicyStatus, GetBucketPublicAccessBlock, GetAccountPublicAccessBlock". I was able to reproduce the error and then fix it by the above solution.

Comment: @Sandeep how were you able to reproduce the error? I imagine the "Access" column having the value "Error" could be due to multiple reasons. I doubt you had a similar setup as described in my question. The solution from Mohammad did not work for me as my console had full access rights.

Comment: @CoffeeConverter2000Pro full access rights will always work fine. Here we are talking about fine grained access control. The permissions that i mentioned are the minimum required permissions for console to access bucket list without error.

Comment: @MohammadSelimMiah, yes and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This answer is missing `s3:ListAccessPoints`, see @CamBeeler's answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

from the AWS documentation
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-error-access-field/

s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock,
s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock,
s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus,
s3:GetBucketAcl,
s3:ListAccessPoints

...
And i added the following
...
"s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
"s3:GetBucketLocation"

Now all of my bucket items list, have full "access" information...including the Permission -> Permissions overview (inside the bucket)

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowS3ListAllBuckets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Were you editing your bucket/iam policy? If so it might be because of this issue: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/